# Como ejecutar otra ventana de windows forms mientras cargar mi Loader C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, preloader

cree un loader para que mientras se termina de cargar datos a mi datagridview este se muestre al usuario y no se quede sin mostrar nada despues de loguearse, entonces lo que pasa es que cuando termina de ejecutarse mi loader pasa a ejecutarse el menu de mi aplicacion pero este todavia tiene que cargar los datos a mi datagridview por lo que no tendria sentido el loader, por eso queria saber si hay una manera de que mientras se ejecuta mi loader este a la vez ejecute mi form principal para que termine de cargar datos a mi datagridview. Les comparto mi codigo que tengo actualmente:

Este codigo es de mi boton login:

```
        if (txtUser.Text == "Usuario" && txtPassword.Text == "Contraseña")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Se ingreso correctamente", "Bienvenido" + " " + txtUser.Text);
            VariablesGlobales.Validacion = txtUser.Text;
            txtUser.Clear();
            txtPassword.Clear();
            this.Hide();
            PreLoader loader = new PreLoader();
            loader.ShowDialog();
            ViewUser mainMenu = new ViewUser();
            mainMenu.Show();
           
        }
        else if (txtUser.Text == "aguripue" && txtPassword.Text == "viernes.02")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Se ingreso correctamente", "Bienvenido" + " " + txtUser.Text);
            VariablesGlobales.Validacion = txtUser.Text;
            txtUser.Clear();
            txtPassword.Clear();
            //ViewAdmin mainMenu = new ViewAdmin();
            //mainMenu.Show();
            //this.Hide();

        }
```

Es otro es de mi loader:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Opacity < 1) this.Opacity += 0.05;
        circularProgressBar1.Value += 1;
        if (circularProgressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer2.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity -= 0.1;
        if (this.Opacity == 0)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
    private void PreLoader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity= 0.0;
        timer1.Start();
        circularProgressBar1.Value = 0;
        circularProgressBar1.Minimum= 0;
        circularProgressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    }
```

Comment: revisa la clase backgroundworker, creo que te podría servir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker

Answer (score 0):

Para casos de asincronía como este una mejor opción es usar Task.
Te permiten cargar datos sin bloquear el hilo principal, además te informa el avance de la tarea y puede ser usado con el progressbar.

```
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
         { 
          IniciarLoader();
          ObtenerDatosGridView();
         });

          Task.WaitAll(task); //Esperar que complete la obtencion de datos
          CargarGridView()
          CerrarLoader();
```